# Docker. Образ python

Tags: docker

Docker -- это развитие виртуальных ОС? Если да, то в таком случае, любой образ -- есть некая ОС. Будь то ubuntu, centOs или иное. Но в таком случае, мне совершенно, непонятно, как исходным образом может быть, например python. Т.е. как можно в dockerfile использовать

```
FROM python:3.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вы посмотрите в [`Dockerfile` у `python:3.5`](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/6ebbaa8a56cdf4021c78e87b3872be3861ac072a/3.5/jessie/Dockerfile#L7) (ищется на [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/)), и увидите там:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie
```

У [него](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/587934fb063d770d0611e94b57c9dd7a38edf928/jessie/Dockerfile#L1), в свою очередь:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-scm
```

И так далее:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-curl
```

И находим ОС:

```
FROM debian:jessie
```

Но это мало должно вас волновать, т. к. суть этого образа в том, чтобы предоставить вам предварительно настроенную среду с готовым к работе Python, безотносительно того, на каком дистрибутиве эта среда построена. К тому же, общие (shared) метки имеют обыкновение меняться со временем, сопроводители (maintainers) образа могут и сменить дистр-основу*. Уверенным можно быть лишь в том, что там будет интерпретатор Python.

Если вам нужно существенное количество зависимостей, никак не связанных с самим Python, помимо Python; может быть предпочтительнее образ конкретного дистрибутива, в который вам будет проще все эти зависимости установить.

[Канонический образ `python`](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/), кстати, поставляется в разных сортах, в том числе на базе разных дистрибутивов: Alpine, разные версии Debian, Windows Server Core.

---

<sub>* По смыслу образа и метки это возможно, технически это возможно, но это может многим сломать совместимость, так что вероятность этого я бы расценивал, как крайне низкую.</sub>

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, вопрос от не юзавшего докер: правильно ли я понимаю, что в пределе каждый образ вот так вот тащит в зависимостях свою собственную ОС (дебианы всех версий, убунты всех версий, alpin'ы всех версий, что там ещё есть), из-за чего куча разных образов очень быстро сожрут свободное место на диске?

Comment: @andreymal да, верно. Против этого работает дедупликация образов и использование более компактных базовых образов вроде alpine. Плюс из образов стараются выкидывать всё лишнее: к примеру, ядро и связанные с его обслуживанием утилиты, т. к. используется в итоге ядро хоста. Так что место на диске сжирается не шибко быстро, но безусловно быстрее, чем при ручной настройке продуктов из образов без докера на одной системе.